# Site Maps: Showing animations in a site map the user has to navigate through

Tags: sitemap

I need to make sitemap for a microsite.

To add in some background detail, the site will be focused on raising Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD). I am still fairly new at writing site maps as well.

The idea is to keep the site "simple". The user will land at the site, they will be promoted to start a patient journey. They will then be presented with animations for 3 patients at different stages of the their COPD condition. The three patient stories will be presented one after the other. After this they will be sent to a page that has the information and links to other pages etc. The client wants the user to be able replay each story afterwards if the user desires it.

**My question is, are there particular ways to show this or what would be the best way to present this?**

At first I thought I would do one branch from the landing page, list the three profiles, then on a second branch from the landing page, list the page with information. Whilst I think this covers all the content, I don't think it makes it clear the user will see the animations first[image]

Then I thought why not start with the landing page, and then have each patient profile branch from each other as per the image below. I think this is a little more clear on the site structure. However, it looks like you have to drill through a lot of page to get to content and I am wondering if this is looking more like a user flow rather than a site map. I could condense the patient profiles into one box and make a note of the content.

Is there particular ways to show this or a good way to show this?

[image]

Comment: "they will be promoted to start a patient journey" - "prompted" maybe?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just so I understand: You are looking for a visualization of a draft design (and currently think about sitemaps)? And the draft design proposes to show a few (patient) stories (without user interaction) plus links to further information/assets (which would require user interaction to go there)?

Answer (score 1):

You can map **User Journey Map**.

What you presented is a cursorily -  **Information Architecture**.

---

On **X axis** it's time, every **block** [in stages of journey] are **chapters** (patient stories etc.)

The map present road from beginning to accomplish goal.

By defining the goals that the user accomplishes, conversions can be measured at every stage

[image]

---

**Information Architecture** maps the structure of the entire page (often also with processes) - and it is worth using it in communication with developers, or at the initial design stage.

[image]